# Bit bucket error while getting clone

Tags: repository, bitbucket, git-clone

I have created a clone to Bit bucket to upload my code whenever I am trying to fetch clone from bit bucket getting this kind of error **Git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)** I want to upload my latest code daily. I have no more detail about it, So it is not possible for me to give more explanation regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for comment but i am not using GitHub may be Bit bucket having different compare to GiHub.

Comment: yes Github and Bitbucket are different but I think context of given answer apply on both.

Comment: Ok i will try that one. :)